# Find a marker from markers

Tags: leaflet

I collect markers using js below:

```
var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    let lat = data[i]['lat'];
    let lon = data[i]['lon'];
    let numStocks = data[i]['numStocks'];

    var markerIcon = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
        icon: 'fa-number',
        markerColor: color,
        shape: 'square',
        number: numStocks,
        prefix: 'fa'
    });

    var marker = new
      L.marker([lat, lon], { icon: markerIcon, riseOnHover: true }).addTo(simLocations)
      .bindPopup(popUp).on('click', markerOnClick);

     markers.addLayer(marker);
 }
```

in some cases I need to find a marker using lat,lng parameters from the markers, I try below but I don't know how to get the marker using the lat,lng

I expect to do something like below:

```
var findLat = -6.22843;
var findLng = 107.00091;

var foundMarker = // here I don't have idea on how to find a marker using findLat, findLng from the markers
```

so I can show it using js below:

```
var latLngs = [foundMarker.getLatLng()];
var markerBounds = L.latLngBounds(latLngs);
map.fitBounds(markerBounds, { padding: [50, 50] });
foundMarker.openPopup();
```

need advice.

many thanks